# Why am I getting "useContext is not a function" or "context is not defined"?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use context in my stateless component. I updated my react to v16.8.0 and added useContext, however, I keep getting these two errors and don't know what else to do. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { LanguageContext } from "./languageContext";
import { useContext } from "react";

function StripeButton() {
  const context = useContext(LanguageContext);
  const stripe = Stripe("pk_live_5PjwBk9dSdW7htTKHQ3HKrTd");

  const [error, setError] = useState();

  const handleClick = () => {
    stripe
      .redirectToCheckout({
...
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        id="UrgentCheckedButtonYES"
        className="btn-primary"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        {this.context.main.name}
        <br />
      </button>
      <div>{error}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default StripeButton;
StripeButton.contextType = LanguageContext;
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to import `useContext` like this:

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
```

Comment: I tried this but I keep getting "useContext is not a function"

Comment: Maybe try changing your first line to: `import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";`

Comment: I have the same problem, wud u plz have a look at my code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hagtbf?file=Cart.tsx  I ONLY get the DEFAULT VALUE, not the set value.

Answer (score 3):

`const { useContext } = React`

useContext is exported as method property of React

Comment: what should I do instead? if I don't put that line I get "useContext is not defined"

Comment: I'm getting the same error with this import in place. It has other causes.

Comment: Make sure your react version is above 16.8.0

Answer (score 0):

(Tested this in React 18.)

In App.js File:

```
import { createContext } from "react";
import ChildComponent from "./components/ChildComponent";

export const Context = createContext("Default Value");

export default function App() {
    const value = "My Context Value"; 

    return (
        <Context.Provider value={value}> 
            <ChildComponent />
        </Context.Provider>
    );
}
```

In ChildComponent.jsx file:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Context } from "../App";

function ChildComponent() {
    const value = useContext(Context);
    return <h1>{value}</h1>;
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

You can have as many consumers as you want for a single context. If the context value changes,then all consumers are immediately notified and re-rendered.

If the consumer isn't wrapped inside the provider, but still tries to access the context value (using useContext(Context) or <Context.Consumer>), then the value of the context would be the default value argument supplied to createContext(defaultValue) factory function that had created the context.

Comment: I have the same problem, wud u plz have a look at my code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hagtbf?file=Cart.tsx  I ONLY get the DEFAULT VALUE, not the set value.

Comment: @Tanvir https://prnt.sc/p15isI4eUESu here is your solution. You need to wrap your App componet with context provider and need to pass value as props. In this way you can access global props (value) from anywhere you want. Thanks.

Comment: thank u very much bhai, but what mistake did I make at the beginning?

Comment: You wrap wtih context in Cart component rather than App. Remember you should wrap your component which is core/ wrapper of all component. That's simple.